# how download latest file from SFTP ( connection use key file and password ) using bash

Tags: sftp, expect

My main problem is that I can't download the latest file from sftp.
Also, I have permission only for downloading file.
Example of files name: transaction_20200403060011_5e86xxxxxx.08595559.csv.
Downloading all files:

```
   #!/usr/bin/expect
    spawn sftp -i /home/ubuntu/sc_sftp.txt xxx@xxx.com 
    expect "password:"
    send "xxx\n" 
    expect "sftp>"
    send "get *.csv\n"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "exit\n"
    interact
```

I need only latest file, so I try to save file name to .txt file and read the filename that I need.It works fine with bash command. Unfortunately, I cann't load the name of file due to I use spawn and sftp commands. My script, that doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp -i /home/ubuntu/sc_sftp.txt xxx@xxx.com 
expect "password:"
send "xxx\n" 
expect "sftp>"
log_file -noappend RemoteFileList.txt
send "ls -1t\n"
expect "sftp>"
log_file
send "!sed -i '' '/ls -1/d' ./RemoteFileList.txt\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "!sed -i '' '/sftp>/d' ./RemoteFileList.txt\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
interact
set $file `(head -2 RemoteFileList.txt | tail -1)`
spawn sftp -i /home/ubuntu/sc_sftp.txt xxx@xxx.com 
expect "password:"
send "xxx\n" 
expect "sftp>"
send "get $file\n"
interact
```

and errors:

```
can't read "file": no such variable
    while executing
"set $file `(head -2 RemoteFileList.txt | tail -1)`"
    (file "./s.sh" line 16)
```

When I have added these commands:

```
send "ls -1t\n"
expect -re "(.+)\r\nsftp>"
send " $expect_out(0,string)"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

I've got:

```
sftp> ls -1t
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
sftp>   ls -1t
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
sftp>
sftp> file1.csv
Invalid command.
sftp>
sftp> file2.csv
sftp>
sftp> file3.csv
sftp>
sftp> sftp>exit
Invalid command.
```

Could anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Tcl is also a general purpose programming language. You can use it for all the string manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the more tedious aspects of expect. You'll do something like this:

```
send "ls -1t\n"
expect -re "(.+)\r\nsftp>"
```

Now the contents of those parentheses (which will be the command "ls -1t" followed by the actual results) is stored in the array variable `$expect_out(1,string)` -- no spaces around the comma.

expect uses `\r\n` for line breaks.

If you need help parsing the results, post here.

---

After

```
send "ls -1t\n"
expect -re "(.+)\r\nsftp>"
```

$expect_out(0,string) contains

```
ls -1t\r\nfile1.csv\r\nfile2.csv\r\nfile3.csv\r\nsftp>
```

$expect_out(1,string) contains

```
ls -1t\r\nfile1.csv\r\nfile2.csv\r\nfile3.csv
```

When you do `send " $expect_out(0,string)"`

```
sftp>  ls -1t
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
sftp>
sftp> file1.csv
Invalid command.
sftp>
sftp> file2.csv
sftp>
sftp> file3.csv
sftp>
sftp> sftp>exit
Invalid command.
```

You can see the `ls` command again.
Then you see the "invalid command" error
for `file1.csv` attempting to be executed as a command. I'm surprised you
don't also show errors for "file2.csv" and "file3.csv" as commands.

You get "invalid command" for exit because you have actually sent `sftp> exit\n`. 
The "sftp> " part was the tail end of $expect_out(0,string) -- you did not
"hit enter" when you sent that.

To get the most recent file, you want the first line of output from the `ls -1t` command:

```
send "ls -1t\r"
expect -re "(.+)\r\nsftp>"

set lines [split $expect_out(1,string) "\n"]
set first_file [lindex $lines 1]
set first_file [string trimright $first_file "\r"]

set timeout -1
send "get $first_file\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still I cannot parse the name of file. I've try something like `get $expect_out(1,string)` , but it doesn't work. I suppose that I missing something. I will be grateful for the help

Comment: What is the content of `$expect_out(1,string)`?

Comment: i think names for all 3 files that I have on sftp, i have added content to the post.